# PHP OO Problemas com Classes

Tags: php, mysql

Boa Noite, estou tentando implementar um método que cadastra o comentario do usuario no banco de dados na tabela comentario que possui a chave estrangeira id_usuario. Como faço para ter acesso a esse id_usuario? Tentei através do meu método getIdUsuario da classe Usuario, mas ele retorna null. Quando o usuário faz o login no sistema estou passando todas as informações do select pelas funcões set() e mesmo assim ele retorna nulo.

```js
<? php
require_once("classes/Conexao.class.php");

class UsuarioDAO {
  function __construct() {
    /
   $this->con = new Conexao(); 
   $this->pdo = $this->con->Connect(); /
  }

  public
  function existeUsuario($email) {

      $query = $this - > pdo - > prepare("SELECT * FROM 'usuario' WHERE  email = '$email'");
      var_dump($query);
      $query - > execute();

      if ($query - > rowCount() >= 1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }

    } //fecha metodo existe

  public
  function logar($usuario) {
    try {
      $query = $this - > pdo - > prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  email = :email AND senha = :senha");

      $param = array(
        ":email" => $usuario - > getEmail(),
        ":senha" => $usuario - > getSenha()
      );
      $query - > execute($param);
      if ($query - > rowCount() >= 1) {
        while ($row = $query - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $usuario - > setNome($row['nome']);
          $usuario - > setEmail($row['email']);
          $usuario - > setSenha($row['senha']);
          $usuario - > setIdUsuario($row['id_usuario']);

        }
        $usuario_id = $usuario - > getIdUsuario();

        return $usuario; //executa a sql com os parametros 
      }

    } catch (PDOException $ex) { //caso haja erro
      echo "ERRO:" + $ex - > getMessage(); //exibe o erro
    }
  }

  public
  function cadastrar($usuario) {
      try {
        $param = array(
          ":nome" => $usuario - > getNome(),
          ":email" => $usuario - > getEmail(),
          ":senha" => $usuario - > getSenha()
        );

        $email = $usuario - > getEmail();

        if ($this - > existeUsuario($email)) { //se existir usuario com esse email
          echo "Usuário ja cadastrado!";
          return false;
        } else {
          $query = $this - > pdo - > prepare("INSERT INTO usuario(nome, email, senha) 
                                        VALUES (:nome, :email, :senha)");
          $query - > execute($param); //executa a sql com os parametros    
          return true;

        }

      } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo "ERRO:" + $ex - > getMessage();
      }
    } //fecha a funcao

} //fecha classe
?>
```

```html
<?php

require_once("/classes/Conexao.class.php"); //Incluimos o arquivo de conexão.
require_once("classes/entidade/Usuario.class.php");
require_once("classes/dao/UsuarioDAO.class.php");
class comentarioDAO { //Criamos uma classe chamada cometarioDAO

function __construct() { //Método contruct inicia automáricamente quando a classe é instanciada.
    $this->con = new Conexao(); //Propriedade con instancia nossa classe de conexao.
    $this->pdo = $this->con->Connect(); //Propriedade con acessa o método Connect que esta dentro da classe conexao.
}

public function cadatrarComentario(comentario $entComentario) {//Criamos um método que será responsável por gravar os comentários, como parâmetro ele recebe nossa entidade comentário. 
    try { //Executa nosso código
        ////pagina, nome, e-mail, comentário, data, hora, ip e status
        $usuario = new Usuario();
        $usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
        $usuarioDAO->logar($usuario);
        $email = $usuario->getEmail();

        print_r($usuario);
 
        $query1 = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM usuario WHERE email = $email");

        $resultId = $query1->execute(array(':email'=>email));


        while ($row = $resultId->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $usuario->setIdUsuario($row['id_usuario']);
            
        }
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO comentario (comentario, data, hora, id_usuario) 
                                    VALUES ( :comentario, :data, :hora, :idUsuario)");

        $param = array(//Criamos um array associativo, onde temos :nome será trocado pelo valor vindo do nosso método get da entidade, estes dados erão tratados apra evitar probleamas
            ":comentario" => $entComentario->getComentario(),
            ":data" => date("Y/m/d"),
            ":hora" => date("h:i:s"),
            ":idUsuario" => $usuario->getIdUsuario()
        );
        
        return $stmt->execute($param); // Aqui executamos nosso SQL e passamos os parâmetros, o reusltado é retornado no nosso método

    } catch (PDOException $ex) { //Se houver algum erro no nosso código vamos criar uma exceção para informar onde esta o erro.
        echo "ERRO: " + $ex->getMessage(); //Exibimos a mensagem de erro e pegamos o código do erro.
    }
}

//Método de consulta

public function consultarComentario($pagina) {
    try { //Executa nosso código
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE cm_pagina = :pagina AND cm_status = 1");
        
        $param = array(":pagina" => $pagina);//Neste caso não precisamos chamar a entidade, é mais trabalhoso e apenas vamos passar um valor como parâmetro.
        
        $stmt->execute($param); //Passamos o parâmetro para a execução.
        
       return $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Resumindo aqui retornamos todos os dados da nossa consulta,se quer retornar só um use apenas fetch e não fetchall
        
    } catch (PDOException $ex) { //Se houver algum erro no nosso código vamos criar uma exceção para informar onde esta o erro.
        echo "ERRO: " + $ex->getMessage(); //Exibimos a mensagem de erro e pegamos o código do erro.
    }
}

}

?>
```

```html
<?php
 class Usuario {
  
  protected $idUsuario;
  protected $nome;
  protected $email;
  protected $senha;
  protected $foto; 

  public function getIdUsuario(){
   return $this->idUsuario;
  }
  public function setIdUsuario($idUsuario){
   $this->idUsuario = $idUsuario;
  }
  public function getNome(){
   return $this->nome;
  }
  public function setNome($nome){
    $this->nome = $nome;
  }

  public function getEmail(){
   return $this->email;
  }
  public function setEmail($email){
   $this->email = $email;
  }

  public function getSenha(){
   return $this->senha;
  }
  public function setSenha($senha){
   $this->senha = $senha;
  }

  public function getFoto(){
   return $this->foto;
  }
  public function setFoto($foto){
   $this->foto = $foto;
  }


  
  

 }//fecha a classe
?>
```

Nao consigo acessar o idUsuario entre as classes

Comment: Corrigi a query e tbm a chamada do método logar que pede um objeto como parametro dessa maneira:  $usuarioDAO->logar($usuario); Mas no var_dump do getEmail ele vem nulo

Comment: No método logar retorne o objeto `$usuario` e não true.

Comment: Continua não acessando os atributos da classe Usuario

Comment: Será que é o encapsulamento? Pq os atributos estao como protected e a minha classe ComentarioDAO fica em outra pasta.

Comment: Como esta a visibilidade dos atributos da classe usuario?

Comment: Faz o prepared certo no email: 
`$query1 = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM usuario WHERE email = :email");`

        `$resultId = $query1->execute(array(':email' => $email));`

Comment: Precisa tbm de um fetch em (`$resultId`) para pegar o resultado e passar no insert.

Comment: Não entendi como usar o fetch

Comment: deu certo o insert?

Comment: Nao, o problema está no $email que não é capturado no getEmail, não sei como acessar esse atributo, parece que quando instancio a classe Usuario se cria um novo usuário com os atributos vazios.

Comment: Sobre instanciar a classe, é a base de Orientação a Objeto, sempre que você instanciar a classe ela vai criar um objeto novo, com todos os atributos zerados. Quando dá um "new user();" você precisa "popular" ele com dados. Seu problema maior aparentemente é fazer esses dados, do usuário, chegarem aí. Qual o fluxo do programa, antes de chegar na função `cadastrarComentario`? (Que por sinal, está faltando um s na definição. ;D)

Comment: Você provavelmente precisa salvar (Ou buscar) quem é esse usuário pela sessão, ou por cookies ou algo do tipo, pra você "saber" quem está logado, comentando no sistema. No caso do PHP vale olhar como funciona $_SESSION.

Comment: Como poderia aplicar session entre as classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu usuário sempre vai voltar vazio, ao cadastrar comentário você está criando uma nova instância (vazia) de Usuario e enviando para o método `$usuarioDAO->logar($usuario);`. Você não está enviando parâmetro nenhum para a sua consulta, por isso ela não vai achar nada e seu método vai sempre retornar o objeto Usuário vazio que enviou anteriormente.

Sua confusão está na variável `$usuario`, quando você loga e seta os valores no objeto utilizando os métodos públicos abaixo:

```
$usuario - > setNome($row['nome']);
$usuario - > setEmail($row['email']);
$usuario - > setSenha($row['senha']);
$usuario - > setIdUsuario($row['id_usuario']);
```

Você preencheu seu objeto, ok! Mas as variáveis no php são voláteis, ou seja, elas somente existem enquanto um script estiver sendo executado, ao se mudar de uma página para outra elas deixam de existir (a menos claro, que sejam transferidas para a próxima página [get ou post], ou definidas como global).

Ao instanciar novamente o objeto `Usuario` no método `cadatrarComentario()` que você criou, você NÃO está chamando aquele usuário que logou anteriormente, porque aquele objeto "morreu" a partir do momento que seu script terminou a execução. Na realidade aí você está criando um novo objeto na memória VAZIO, sem nada!

O recomendado ai seria utilizar [sessão](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.session.php) no php, um exemplo básico nesse caso seria:

1 - Inicie a sessão antes de tudo no seu arquivo php que irá utilizar:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // seu código abaixo
?>
```

2 - Ao logar o usuário armazene o id dele ou outra informação que irá precisar (básicas, sem comprometer a integridade do mesmo e seu banco de dados) para não efetuar uma nova consulta no banco a cada vez que precisar:

```
public function logar($usuario) {
    try {
        $query = $this - > pdo - > prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  email = :email AND senha = :senha");
        $param = array(
            ":email" => $usuario - > getEmail(),
            ":senha" => $usuario - > getSenha()
        );
        $query - > execute($param);
        if ($query - > rowCount() >= 1) {
            while ($row = $query - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

               // GUARDANDO NA SESSÃO AO INVÉS DE DO OBJETO
                $_SESSION['ID_USER'] = $row['id_usuario'];


        // Continuação do seu código...
```

Quando for cadastrar o comentário, inicie a sessão no começo do arquivo php (no caso `ComentarioDAO.class.php`) como no passo 1 e quando precisar do id do usuário chame a variável que criou na sessão assim:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO comentario (comentario, data, hora, id_usuario) VALUES ( :comentario, :data, :hora, :idUsuario)");

$param = array(//Criamos um array associativo, onde temos :nome será trocado pelo valor vindo do nosso método get da entidade, estes dados erão tratados apra evitar probleamas
    ":comentario" => $entComentario->getComentario(),
    ":data" => date("Y/m/d"),
    ":hora" => date("h:i:s"),
    ":idUsuario" => $_SESSION['ID_USER'] // Chamando aqui o valor que armazenou
);
```

Você pode armazenar os valores que precisar criando os nomes que desejar (`$_SESSION['NOME_USER']`, `$_SESSION['NOME']`...).

Lembrando que é um exemplo simples, procure ler melhor sobre o assunto, existem outras questões como por exemplo a segurança de tudo isso.

Espero que essa breve explicação te ajude.

Abraços

Comment: Muito obrigada @Mastria