# PHP Como passar valores de atributos entre as classes

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho duas classes distintas Usuario e Comentário, uso a classe ComentarioDAO para gravar os comentarios no bd, mas preciso do atributo usuario_id que fica na classe Usuário que fica no método getUsuarioId(). Quando instancio o objeto Usuario() na classe ComentarioDAO cria-se um novo objeto com os atributos zerados. Como poderia passar esse valor id para outra classe? Tentei com uma variável global mas não deu certo.

```js
<?php
 require_once("classes/Conexao.class.php");

 class UsuarioDAO{
  function __construct(){
   $this->con = new Conexao(); 
   $this->pdo = $this->con->Connect(); 
  }

  public function existeUsuario($email){
   
   $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM 'usuario' WHERE  email = '$email'");
   var_dump($query);
   $query->execute();

   if ($query->rowCount() >= 1){
    return true;
   }else{
    return false;
   }

  }//fecha metodo existe

  public function logar($usuario){
   try{
    $param = array(
     ":email" => $usuario->getEmail(),
     ":senha" => $usuario->getSenha()
     );
    $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  email = :email AND senha = :senha");
    $query->execute($param); 
    $senha = $usuario->getSenha();

    if ($query->rowCount()>=1) {
     while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      if ($row['senha'] == $senha) {
       $_SESSION['idUsuario'] = $row['id_usuario'];   
      }
     }
    }
      return $usuario; 
  
   
   } catch(PDOException $ex){ //caso haja erro
    echo "ERRO:"+ $ex->getMessage(); //exibe o erro
   }
  }


  public getIdUsuario(){
   return $_SSESION['idUsuario'];
  }

  public function cadastrar($usuario){
   try {
     $param = array(
     ":nome" =>$usuario->getNome(),
     ":email" => $usuario->getEmail(),
     ":senha" => $usuario->getSenha()
     );

     $email = $usuario->getEmail();

    if ($this->existeUsuario($email)) { 
     echo "Usuário ja cadastrado!";
     return false;
    }else{
     $query = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario(nome, email, senha) 
                                        VALUES (:nome, :email, :senha)");       
     $query->execute($param);     
      return true; 
   
    }
    
   } catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "ERRO:"+ $ex->getMessage(); 
   }
  }//fecha a funcao

 }//fecha classe
?>
```

```html
<?php
 class Usuario {
  
  protected $idUsuario;
  protected $nome;
  protected $email;
  protected $senha;
  protected $foto; 


  public function getIdUsuario(){
   return $this->idUsuario;
  }
  public function setIdUsuario($idUsuario){
   $this->idUsuario = $idUsuario;
  }
  public function getNome(){
   return $this->nome;
  }
  public function setNome($nome){
    $this->nome = $nome;
  }

  public function getEmail(){
   return $this->email;
  }
  public function setEmail($email){
   $this->email = $email;
  }

  public function getSenha(){
   return $this->senha;
  }
  public function setSenha($senha){
   $this->senha = $senha;
  }

  public function getFoto(){
   return $this->foto;
  }
  public function setFoto($foto){
   $this->foto = $foto;
  }


  
  

 }//fecha a classe
?>
```

```js
<?php

session_start();
require_once("/classes/Conexao.class.php"); //Incluimos o arquivo de conexão.
require_once("classes/entidade/Usuario.class.php");
require_once("classes/dao/UsuarioDAO.class.php");
class comentarioDAO { //Criamos uma classe chamada cometarioDAO

    function __construct() { 
        $this->con = new Conexao(); 
        $this->pdo = $this->con->Connect(); 
    }

    public function cadatrarComentario(comentario $entComentario) { 
        try { 
           
 
            $query1 = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM usuario WHERE email = $email");

            $resultId = $query1->execute(array(':email'=>email));


            while ($row = $resultId->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        $usuario->setIdUsuario($row['id_usuario']);
                
            }
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO comentario (comentario, data, hora, id_usuario) 
                                        VALUES ( :comentario, :data, :hora, :idUsuario)");

            $param = array(/
                ":comentario" => $entComentario->getComentario(),
                ":data" => date("Y/m/d"),
                ":hora" => date("h:i:s"),
                ":idUsuario" => $usuario->getIdUsuario()
            );
            
            return $stmt->execute($param); 
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo "ERRO: " + $ex->getMessage(); 
    }

    //Método de consulta

    public function consultarComentario($pagina) {
        try { //Executa nosso código
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE cm_pagina = :pagina AND cm_status = 1");
            
            $param = array(":pagina" => $pagina);
            
            $stmt->execute($param); 
            
           return $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            
        } catch (PDOException $ex) { 
            echo "ERRO: " + $ex->getMessage(); 
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Passe o usuario_id no método construtor do Usuário, ou crie um atributo autor_id na classe Comentário.

Comment: Essa pergunta é a mesma da [sua pergunta anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56426/php-oo-problemas-com-classes)?

Comment: Sim, @bfavarretto. Não é correto ficar criando tópicos assim, mas não consegui resolver este problema.

Answer (score 2):

Podes passar o `usuario_id` para a tua classe `ComentarioDAO` quer por parâmetro no construtor (se existir), quer como parâmetro da função que o utiliza:

## Exemplos

```php
class ComentarioDAO {

  /* @var integer
   */
  private $usuario_id;


  /**
   * Instanciate the ComentarioDAO class
   *
   * @param integer $usuario_id User ID.
   */
  function __construct($usuario_id=0) {

    $this->usuario_id = $usuario_id;
  }


  public function fazerQualquerCoisa() {

    echo $this->usuario_id;
  }

  public function fazerQualquerCoisa2($usuario_id=0) {

    echo $usuario_id;
  }
}
```

Depois seria algo dentro deste género:

- Passar como parâmetro do construtor

  ```php
  $userClass = new usuario();

  $commentClass = new ComentarioDAO($userClass->getUsuarioId());

  $commentClass->fazerQualquerCoisa();
  ```
- Passar como parâmetro dum método:

  ```php
  $userClass = new usuario();

  $commentClass = new ComentarioDAO();

  $commentClass->fazerQualquerCoisa2($userClass->getUsuarioId());
  ```

Comment: estou usando as classes dessa forma

Comment: Se eu criar um construtor na classe Usuario como poderei pegar esse id na classe ComentarioDAO?

Comment: O `construct` não te vai permitir passar valore entre classes... Ele pode é receber valores por parâmetro para os disponibilizar para os seus métodos.

Answer (score 0):

Procure por ORMs em php, um muito bom é o Eloquent, usado no Laravel, eles já abstraem todo o DAO e o CRUD

Caso não queira usar ORMs, você pode colocar um atributo `usuario` dentro da classe Comentario, daí é só fazer:

`$c = new Comentario;`

`$c->usuario = $usuario;`

Se os atributos da classe Usuario forem públicos você pode acessá-los normalmente `$c->usuario->id`, caso contrário use os metódos `$c->usuario->getId()`

Sua classe Comentario ficaria assim:

```
class Comentario {
  public usuario;
  ...  
}
```